# LookAhead Regex in .Net - unexpected result

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am a bit puzzled with my Regex results (and still trying to get my head around the syntax). I have been using http://regexpal.com/ to test out my expression, and its works as intended there, however in C# its not as expected.

Here is a test - an expression of the following: `(?=<open>).*?(?=</open>)`

on an input string of:
`<open>Text 1 </open>Text 2 <open>Text 3 </open>Text 4 <open>Text 5 </open>`

I would expect a result back of `<open>Text1 <open>Text 2 <open>Text 3...` etc

However when I do this in C# it only returns the first match of `<open>Text1`

How do I get all five 'results' back from the Regex?

```
    Regex exx = new Regex("(?=<open>).*?(?=</open>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    string input = "<open>Text 1</open> Text 2 <open> Text 3 </open> Text 4 <open> Text 5 </open>";
    string result = Regex.Match(input, exx.ToString(), exx.Options).ToString();
```

Comment: I see only three matches there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Match`.

```
PS Home:> $s = '<open>Text 1 </open>Text 2 <open>Text 3 </open>Text 4 <open>Text 5 </open>'
PS Home:> $re = '(?=<open>).*?(?=</open>)'
PS Home:> @([regex]::Match($s, $re)).Length
1
PS Home:> @([regex]::Matches($s, $re)).Length
3
```

As the documentation for [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx) states:

> Searches an input string for a substring that matches a regular expression pattern and returns the first occurrence as a single [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) object.

whereas for [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx):

> Searches an input string for all occurrences of a regular expression and returns all the successful matches.

**Note:** *What you're doing here seems very wrong. If what you're dealing with is XML or a similar language, then please don't use regular expressions to parse it. You'll [get mad otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) with nested structures.*

Comment: In that case, you can improve your karma by upvoting and accepting Johannes' answer (see the up-triangle and checkbox next to this post?

Comment: I missed the Matches option. Thanks for that link as well, I am doing some basic HTML parsing/scraping, nothing too complex (I think...) I was using a for loop and trawling through the string byte by byte, but thought a Regex would be better (its certainly a lot less code!), Ill have a good read through that question though.

Comment: I can accept the answer (and thanks for pointing me to the place, I was looking for some text to click on, not an image!), but I cant upvote unless I become a member :(

Comment: @Aaron: For HTML scraping you can use the HTML Agility Pack (http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) which should be a lot more robust than using regular expressions.

Comment: @Aaron: Two more rep points to go, and you'll be able to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to have `<open>` at the start of every match? Why not use lookbehind, too?

```
(?<=<open>).*?(?=</open>)
```

Comment: Ah, good point. It looks bad in the test data I used, but the real data I am parsing the opening tag can be helpful. Thanks though, Regex is all new to me, but will take a bit to get used to. Now Johannes has given me something else to look at as well!